# Referencing .styl of a node_module in Brunch

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, stylus, brunch, chaplinjs

I have a brunch-with-Chaplin app. I want to use Twitter Bootstrap, but since it's written in LESS I would prefer to switch to a stylus version. Luckily there is a bootstrap-stylus node_module out there.
So I install it via `npm install bootstrap-stylus`. But then how do I reference the stylus files that are inside the module? Doing

```
@import 'bootstrap-stylus'
```

doesn't work. Neither does appending the `/lib/bootstrap` path.

I have `"bootstrap-stylus": ">= 0.2"` in my `dependencies` in the `package.json` file but still no go. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: should be something like `@import node_modules/bootstrap-stylus`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm installs into your node_modules folder, you can @import stylus files from there.

The line that worked in my test was:

`@import 'node_modules/bootstrap-stylus/lib/bootstrap.styl'`

Answer (score -5):

`node_modules` are for node.js. Brunch is for frontend / html5. You cannot combine them that simple.

You will need to manually copy stuff to `app` or `vendor` directories.

Comment: No, one can use as @generalhenry said the correct `@import` command, and also integrate the javascript through the brunch config file by telling it to also look inside the node_modules directory

Comment: Paul Miller. You can use "frontend" dependencies like: font-awesome, jquery, slick-carousel etc.  via  npm and a node_modules folder will be theirs home